# Is this ruby metaprogramming abuse?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I am new to Ruby, and have a gem that I am making to interact with a JSONRPC API and basically all calls and responses are similar enough, that every API call can be handled with one function, like:

`Module::api_command('APINamespace.NamespaceMethod')`

but I would like to also (for convenience sake) be able to do:

`Module::APINamespace.NamespaceMethod`

Is there any reason not to do this by using Module.const_missing to return a dummy class that has a method_missing which will allow passing the call from `Module::APINamespace.NamespaceMethod` to `Module::api_command('APINamespace.NamespaceMethod')`

Is there a more elegant or civilized way to do this?

Comment: well? did my answer do what you wanted? still hvaen't heard back from you..

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I'm sorry, but to my mind that hack is *ridiculous*. :)

First of all, i'm assuming that your `api_command` method is actually invoking methods on the `APINamespace` module, as implied by this line: `Module::api_command('APINamespace.NamespaceMethod')`

Given the above, why not just set a constant equal to  `APINamespace` in your module?

```
MyModule::APINamespace = ::APINamespace
MyModule::APINamespace.NamespaceMethod()
```

**UPDATE:**

I'm still not entirely understanding your situation, but perhaps this:

```
module MyModule
    def self.const_missing(c)
        Object.const_get(c)
    end
end
```

Now you can invoke any top-level constant as if it was defined on your module; say there was a module called `StrangeAPI` at top-level, if you use the hack above, you can now invoke its methods as follows:

```
MyModule::StrangeAPI.Blah()
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: I figured it was a pretty goofy, way of doing it, which is why i posted the question :p.  I am not sure i understand the = ::APINamespace assignment, whats going on there?

Comment: @re5et, if i understood what you're doing correctly -- there actually exists a module called `APINamespace` that holds the methods you want to invoke...but you are currently invoking them through `MyModule.api_command()`. My solution just binds a constant called `MyModule::APINamespace` to the global `APINamespace` constant...enabling you to directly invoke the `ApiNamespace` methods from within your module by going `MyModule::APINamespace.NameSpaceMethod()`

Comment: the problem is there are a bunch of namespaces, which all have their own methods.  I was wondering if there was something I could do other than defining them each as a constant in the module.